# Looking for a magical girl anime episode where the heroine is turned into a baby

Tags: hime-chan-no-ribbon

I'm looking for a particular episode from a magical girl anime, but I don't know the name of that anime. In the episode I'm looking for, the heroine finds a baby, and in order to communicate with it, she uses her powers to turn herself into a baby. However, because babies can't speak very well, she can't pronounce the magical words to change back. Does anyone know which anime this could refer to, and which episode? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details, as specified in http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/891/what-criteria-should-we-use-for-qcing-for-all-identification-request-questions/892

Comment: I wish I could, but that's all the details I have; I got the description from a person's comment on another website, but said description was that vague. I'm sorry for not being able to provide more details... :(

Answer (score 6):

I know a manga (which has an anime too) where **a girl turned herself as a baby**, but **had difficulty to change back due to the "baby language"**, but the purpose was not for talking with another baby but for being a replacement until the actual baby is back.

The manga is [Hime-chan no Ribbon](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2037/Hime-chan_no_Ribbon), in the books, this event happened in a bonus chapter of the volume 9.

[image: http://a.mfcdn.net/store/manga/558/cover.jpg?1419502322]

Comment: Thank you very much; I don't know if this is the manga the person was alluding to in the comments I read (He posted this recently, and hasn't left any details since), but that seems close enough to me. I'll still leave the question open for a little while longer, just in case. BTW, I read the chapter you mentioned, and the manga looks adorable as all get up, so I'll check it out further. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome, indeed it's really cute (and it's also fun), I recommend it